# Hitting the 2100 parameter limit and how to improve this query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a fairly complex search system which gets a list of matching courses, then shows a list of filters (career paths) with the number of courses for each filter option. After I have the List of search results, I do a query to get a list of career paths and how many courses have that career path (a course can have multiple career paths and courses can be associated to career paths by CourseVersionId or CourseInfoId (sounds strange but there's a reason). I can't really change the database structure at this point so am just looking for ways to improve this query.

If there is a lot of search results (1200) then I hit the 2100 parameter limit due to the two Contains sections of my query. I can avoid the problem by limiting the results to 1000 but am hoping there is a better way to do this query.

tbCareerPath is my list of career paths which I cache the complete list (about 50) in memory to save on lookups.

tbCourseCareerPath is my lookup table which has fields to associate courses either by CourseVersionId or CourseInfoId (hence the two Contains).

courseResults is my search results list, which could be anywhere up to about 1500 results (unusual but happens).

Here's my query to get the career paths that have courses in the search results, and the number of courses:

```
var q2 = from careerPath in tbCareerPath.Cache()
            let courseCount =
            (
                from courseCareerPath in dc.tbCourseCareerPaths
                where courseCareerPath.CareerPathId == careerPath.CareerPathId &&
                ((from course in courseResults
                select (int?)course.Course.CourseVersionId).Contains(courseCareerPath.CourseVersionId) ||    
                (from course in courseResults
                select (int?)course.Course.CourseInfoId).Contains(courseCareerPath.CourseInfoId))
                select courseCareerPath
            ).Count()
            where courseCount > 0
            orderby courseCount descending, careerPath.CareerPathTitle ascending
            select new Filter()
            {
                Id = careerPath.CareerPathId,
                Title = careerPath.CareerPathTitle,
                RecordCount = courseCount
            };
```